# data fitting with lookup table in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I am currently trying to fit some data with python using scipy.optimize.leastsq. The data that I want to fit is of the form:

```
Mag(H,F,L) = F*sigmap(H) - sigman(H,L)
```

The Sigmap is a numeric integral which is a function of H and takes quite a while to calculate. I do not wish to include the integral as part of the fitting routine as otherwise the integral will be performed repeatedly and increase the time of the fitting routine significantly. As such I want to look up the values of the integral from elsewhere. The code I have used to implement this is:

```
integral = np.loadtxt(text file of form: H_Value Integral_Value)
lookupintegral = dict(integral)
sigmap = F*lookupintegral[H]
```

This is then included within the function which I am fitting to.

When I try to execute the code I generate an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to implement a fitting routine that looks up data rather than calculating it every time?

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that the variable H is a numpy array, which can't be used as a dictionary key. Make sure that the variable H is an integer or float value.

Comment: Sorry not to have been clearer but H has to be a numpy array for the function in SciPy to work. It is basically an array of x values for which y values are fitted.